# Facebook api friends list

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, runtime-error, client-side, friend

I'm using Facebook's javascript SDK to inspect the friends list of users registered in my  application.

I have this call:

```
     FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {     
           FB.api('me/friends', { fields: 'id, first_name, picture', limit: 6 },function(response){
                  MY CODE TO VIEW FRIENDS PICTURE
           });
        }
        else{
                 CODE TO GET ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
  });
```

but in most of cases I get an api error like this:

```
response.error = {
message: unkown error,
code: undefined,
type: http,
subcode: undefined
}
```

I tested it with my account and it works fine, even if I change privacy permission as friend's sharing.

There is something wrong in my code?

Comment: you have a syntax error in your javascript code, not all brackets are closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api('me/friends', { fields: 'id, first_name,picture', limit: 6 },function(response){

    console.log(response);

  });
```

For more detail information use Facebook's graph API  explore :[Facebook Graph aPI](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends?fields=id,first_name&limit=6)

Comment: Using Graph api explorer (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with picture field I obtain a correct response: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cpicture so I believe this is not a problem. I have the same error also with other API like me/permission

Comment: @AlessiaPileri, I think i got the problem, you have missed one closing parenthesis after funtion(response , put that bracket and try once.

Comment: yes, here there isn't the parenthesis after the word response, but in my script it is correct! Unfortunately, my problem isn't so simple :(

Comment: hi @AlessiaPileri, Please update your original code as this code is buggy and have one parenthesis and one curly bracket missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an fql query with FB.api? It offers a great control.

The following FQL return (User ID, First Name and Picture of a friend who is using the application)

```
FB.api(
         {
           method: 'fql.query',
           query: 'SELECT uid,first_name,pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and is_app_user limit 6',
           access_token: token
         }
```

Note: You would better use this condition

```
if (response && response.authResponse) {
```

Instead of:

```
if (response.status == 'connected') {
```

Regards,