# How to get members of facebook group which are only my friends

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch groups & friends from facebook. Also in group members I need only those who are my friends.

This gives me list of friends

```
  FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }
```

This gives me list of groups

```
  FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/groups" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }
```

This gives me list of group members

```
  FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/groups?fields=members" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }
```

Where I get number of members which I cant draw a for loop to find my friends. Any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 0 - FQL Solution**

```
SELECT uid,first_name,pic 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND uid IN (SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid=GROUP_ID)
```

---

Wouldn't the below provide you with a list of members that you could loop through to find your friends?

> Applications can get the list of members that belong to a group by
>   issuing a `GET` request to `/GROUP_ID/members` with an app `access_token`.
>
> If the action is successful, the response will contain:
>
> ```
> Name           Description                              Type
> ID             The id of the user.                      string
> Name           The name of the user.                    string
> administrator  The user is administrator of the group.  boolean
> ```

via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/#read_group_members

Comment: In question there is already mentioned like is there any other way to achieve this instead of for loop. Any way to tell facebook like provide only group member those are in my friend list.

Comment: See my updated answer with the FQL solution. You could make a FQL query via [the API as suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16114134/1085891).